# How do I call a request that has entity in it?

Tags: java, soap, request

(1) The class I described below includes three strings and one entity.

(2) The text I sent as a call is as follows.

(3) But I'm making the mistake.

1:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"tesisatKod", "islemGuid", "islemTutari", "islemTuru"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "secondStageRequest")    
    public class SecondStageRequest {        
        protected String tesisatKod;
        protected String islemGuid;
        //  protected Date sorguSaatTarih;
        protected String islemTutari;
        protected IslemTuru islemTuru;
    }
```

2:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xc="http://xml.cinigaz.com.tr">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" wsse:mustUnderstand="1">
  <wsse:UsernameToken>
     <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
     <wsse:Password>pwd1234</wsse:Password>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xc:secondStageRequest>
         <xc:tesisatKod>bbb</xc:tesisatKod>
         <xc:islemGuid>bbb</xc:islemGuid>
          <xc:islemTutari>bbb</xc:islemTutari>
         <xc:islemTuru>
                 <xc:islemTuruId> 1</xc:islemTuruId>
                 <xc:islemTuruAdi> aaa</xc:islemTuruAdi>
         </xc:islemTuru>

      </xc:secondStageRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

3:

```
WARN 20148 --- [nio-9020-exec-2] s.w.s.s.e.i.PayloadValidatingInterceptor : XML validation error on request: cvc-type.3.1.2: Element 'xc:islemTuru' is a simple type, so it must have no element information item [children].
```

Comment: the error clearly shows islemTuru must be complex.

Comment: As pointed by @Vaibs, the message states that element <xc:islemTuru> can not contain childs, like <xc:islemTuruId> or <xc:islemTuruAdi>. You should change the schema where the types are defined to allow such circustance.

Comment: Your comments worked and error fixed. But  I put breakpoint in endpoint debug from request objects that are full of strings and true. But islemTuru (islemTuruId and islemTuruAdi ) is null.